# Proxying JSSE/SSLContext/SSLEngine?

Tags: java, ssl, jsse

I need to put an SSL connection established by using JSSE through my proxy (tunneling, I believe). Is there any library/property/method for this already, or must I implement this at a low level?

Note this proxy needs to be defined for only a subset of my program. Other HTTP communication in my program will not run through a proxy.

Comment: what is proxy here ?

Comment: @MSach Sach Any remote proxy, mainly something to mask the IP.

Comment: Are you writing the proxy or the server, or just the client?  This is the problem of the proxy and the server, not the client.

Comment: I am writing the proxy (I plan on chaining this one to another proxy). @WarrenDew

Comment: You don't need SSL in a proxy. Just implement the HTTP CONNECT command and then just copy bytes in both directions. SSL should be end to end.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: you can implement your own custom provider, and then specify it when you need a proxy.  I implemented it here with debug functionality: https://tersesystems.com/blog/2018/07/27/debug-java-tls-ssl-provider/